Can Wang's effective resistance algorithms be used on Graph Isomorphism related problems?
Given a large, oracularly defined graph $\Gamma=(V,E)$, Guoming Wang has a paper describing a couple of quantum algorithms for the neat problem of determining the effective resistance between two nodes in the graph, up to some error. I haven't studied his algorithms in a lot of detail but I suspect that Wang is able to estimate the resistance between nodes $V_1$ and $V_2$ based on the spectral decomposition of something like:
$$|\psi\rangle^\pm=\frac {1} {\sqrt 2}|V_1\rangle\pm \frac {1}{\sqrt 2}|V_2\rangle,$$
with respect to the eigenvectors of $\Gamma$ (or maybe of the Laplacian of $\Gamma$).
Wang assumes the graph $\Gamma$ is connected, but must that be so? That is, can we instead turn his algorithm around to decide if the graph $\Gamma$ is connected between the two nodes $V_1,V_2$ (and the resistance is finite), or, alternatively, the graph is not connected (and the resistance is infinite or very large?)
For example, consider the Graph Isomorphism problem of deciding whether two (small) graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ on $n$ vertices are isomorphic. Let the (larger) implicitly/oracularly defined graph $\Gamma$ used in Wang's problem be the Cayley graph of the automorphism group of $G_1\times G_2$ generated with some nice generators of $S_n$; the vertices of $\Gamma$ could correspond to different adjacency matrices of $G_1$ or $G_2$, and the (colored) edges correspond to different generators of $S_n$ permuting the $n$ rows and columns.
Could we not use Wang's work to calculate the resistance between $G_1$ and $G_2$, and if finite conclude that $G_1\cong G_2?$ That is, $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic iff the Cayley graph $\Gamma$ of the automorphism group is connected (and hence there's a current path between them)?
I suspect the answer is "yes" but there's no guarantee as to the accuracy required (and hence, runtime) so as to distinguish infinite resistance from finite resistance...
